# Хэш таблица и картинка

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять что за цифры после ключей: ну Lisa Smith 521-8976 (Что за цифры, объясните)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev хеш код? А что тогда 000 до 255?

Comment: А, вас интересуют цифры 521-8976? Это значения. Телефонные номера, скорее всего.

Comment: Это значения. По ним не идет поиск, разве что полным перебором, и они могут быть одинаковые. Но можно эффективно найти значение по ключу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ассоциативный массив
ключ - Lisa Smith; значение - 521-8976
А 001 - это просто номер ячейки в которой хранится ключ:значение

Надеюсь помог! :)